# Was Question posted?

Tags: support, asking-questions

I tried posting a question a few minutes ago. It seemed to take a long time to post and I did not see any confirmation it posted. How can I tell if my question was posted?

Answer (score 2):

You can see all of your not deleted posts by visiting your profile and looking at either questions or answers. If you're looking for something recent, you can just view your [activity page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/16552/rivercoon?tab=topactivity) and sort the columns by "Newest".

Your most recent question was over a month ago, so it seems that the question you tried to post did not go through.